# create a string variable with all of an array's items

Tags: php

I'd like to create a string variable from an array.

Here's a non working code for conceptualizing it:

```
$list = array('elem1', 'elem2', 'elem3', 'elem4');

$myString = foreach ( $list as $element ){
    '<span>' . $element . '</span><span>|</span>';
};
```

Comment: run your loop, string concatenate the result on a variable that exists outside your loop.

Comment: And what's your question aboout this code? Anything not working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
 <?php
    $lists = array("elem1", "elem2", "elem3", "elem4");
    $string = '';
    
    foreach ($lists as $element){
        $string = $string . ' | '. $element;
    };
      
    echo '<span>' . $string . '</span>';
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is concatenate the results of each iteration of your loop to a variable that exists outside of the loop.

Example:

```
$list = array('elem1', 'elem2', 'elem3', 'elem4');

$myString = '';
foreach ( $list as $element ){
   $myString .= $myString . '<span>' . $element . '</span><span>|</span>';
};

print($myString);
```

Comment: You were missing a crucial `.` which made this code not work (overwriting the variable each time, rather than appending to it). I've [added it for you](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71617299/revisions).

Answer (score 0):

```
$list = array('elem1', 'elem2', 'elem3', 'elem4');

foreach( $list as $element ){
    $myString[] = '<span>' . $element . '</span><span>|</span>';
}

print(implode('', $myString));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).